# Update Image from Secondary View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I need to update an image on the main view controller from a pop up view controller.

The button is called 'Feature2btn' on the Main View (EraViewController) but when I try the following code on the popup view controller it won't work.

It needs to be an immediate update as the main view is still showing in the background and does not reload so the change needs to be directly caused by the action on the pop up view.

```
- (IBAction)purchase:(id)sender {
 HomeController = [[EraViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EraViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_plan.png"];
    [(EraViewController*)HomeController setFeature2Btn:[feature2Btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

Comment: I'll try to add a selector on my button that trigger a method (in main) that is responsible to update image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (at least) two ways to do this:

1. You use a notification that one controller listens to and the other sends at the appropriate time.
2. You create a delegate protocol that the first controller implements and the second on calls.

The delegate one is a bit more complicated but generally considered good style. The notification one is not bad, either, but slightly less "elegant".
I will describe the notification based one here, because it seems ok for your case and would also allow to react to the purchase in multiple places by just registering for the notification there, too.

In the controller that has the image to be updated, register for a notification in `viewDidAppear:`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateImage:) name:@"UpdateImageNotification" object:nil];
```

Implement the `updateImage:` method:

```
-(void)updateImage:(NSNotification*)note
{
    NSString* newImageName = note.userInfo[@"imageFileKey"];
    // ... update UI with the new image
}
```

Also make sure to deregister for that notification when the view goes away:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

In the other controller, that triggers the update, fire the notification at the appropriate place:

```
-(IBAction)purchase:(id)sender
{
    // ...

    NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"imageFileKey" : newImageName};
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                postNotificationName:@"UpdateImageNotification"
                              object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    // ...
}
```

The `object` parameter in the notification context is to be used to specify if you want to listen to the notifications by *any* object or just by a very specific instance. In many cases the actual instance is not relevant, but you just discern the notifications by their name (like "UpdateImageNotification" in this case).

The `userInfo` dictionary is intended to carry along any information you need to provide with the notification. That's why I introduced a key "imageFileKey" that is associated with the new image name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a small mistake. But before going ahead I just want to confirm whether following is the scenario. Correct me if I am wrong
1. You have mainViewController/HomeViewController (of type EraViewController), where you want to update the image
2. On mainViewController you have a popup screen, in which above code is written. The code is intended to change the button image on mainViewController/HomeViewController

If above is the scenario then I suggest following solution.

**ERROR YOU MADE**

You are creating a new object of EraViewController in the code you posted above and changing the image. According to OOPS concepts, new instance of that controller will be created(a second instance which is not visible on the screen) and you are applying new image in that instance. Now as that instance is not at all visible, you get a feeling that screen is not updating.

**SOLUTION**

There are at-least 3 solution to this problem
1. One solution will be Daniel Schneller gave in answer (with little bit modifications probably)
2. To achieve this through the delegates.
-  You have to write the protocol in the PopViewController and have to implement that in the HomeViewController/mainViewController.
-  As the image changes, in PopViewController, That has to be notified to the mainViewController, using delegate and protocol method.
- So that the mainViewController will get the notification and a protocol method will be executed. In that method you should have a code to update the image on the button.
3. (This is not suggested as this is not a good design)You have maintain the instance of the actual viewController which is visible on the screen (in a variable, lets say homeViewController). Then you can use following code in popupViewController

```
- (IBAction)purchase:(id)sender {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_plan.png"];
    [(EraViewController*)homeViewController setFeature2Btn:[feature2Btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

Hoep this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Yes you are correct in the idea. I am actually using the MJPopupViewController from the following github. https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController, But I am using it for in-app purchases which is why i need to update the image as i need to remove the padlock image that is being displayed.

Comment: You can use the solution given by daniel or you can use a protocol-delegate method to achieve the result.Tell me if you need any help on how to achieve this.

Comment: I've tried Daniel's way and I'm getting loads of errors. I must be doing something wrong... How would I do it using the protocol-delegate method?

Comment: are you aware of writing protocols and delgates. IF not refer to http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/ You have to write a protocol in popviewcontroller to get the notifications about the changes done in the popviewcontroller and you have to handle it in the mainviewcontroller. So MainViewcontroller will be a delegate to handle the notification. Once the protocol and delegate is set, call the delegates method (protocol's method implemented by mainviewcontroller). And in that method update your screen.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
 - (IBAction)purchase:(id)sender 
 {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateimage"        object:imageName];
  }
```

in mainviewcontroller

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    selector:@selector(updateiimage:) name:@"updateimage" object:nil];

 }

- (void) updateiimage:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  NSString * text =[notification object];
   //update Image
 }
```

Comment: That is wrong. The object parameter is not intended to be used like this.

Comment: It works perfectly . If i am wrong then what is proper way to aachive this.

Comment: See my answer. Your solution does work, but that is more by accident than by design. The object parameter is not intended to carry user information, but identify which instance sent the notification.

Comment: this wont work as the ViewDidLoad is not called when dismissing the other view controller as the main view remains in the background and therefore does not reload